# Can't play WAV files using standard gstreamer command

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I can play mp3 files without any problem, also in my application playing PCM data from appsrc is working well, however I have a problem playing a **WAV** file using the gstreamer command:

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=sound.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! alsasink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstwavparse.c(2046): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already installed gstreamer goog plugins?

```
apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

Then try to convert WAV:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=path_of_input_wav_file ! wavparse ! filesink location=path_of_output_file
```

Comment: Yes. I have it already installed. Your command is working fine (I got some result file). So it looks like *wavparse* plugins is OK. *audioconvert* plugin is also fine as command 
    *filesrc location=Sound.mp3 ! mad ! audioconvert ! alsasink* 
is playing fine.